# C# Method in hosting application, turns into class in client application

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been trying to create an application that can receive information from other running applications through WCF.
I've setup a void method in a separate class, created the interface, and hosted the service.

In my Host application I have the following method.

```
public Class ReceivingMethods : IReceivingMethods
{
    Public void HelloWorld(string text)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}
```

and

```
[ServiceContract]
interface iReceivingMethods
{
   [OperationContract]
   void HelloWorld(string text);
}
```

In the client, I would like to do this:

```
HostService client = new HostService();
client.HelloWorld("Hello World");
client.close();
```

But it doesn't work and instead I have to do this.

```
HostService client = new HostService();
HelloWorld hi = new HelloWorld();
hi.text = "Hello World";
client.HelloWorld(hi);
client.close();
```

I've gotten it to work as the former previously in an Application/ASP combination, but not on this application and I cannot find any difference in the setup between the two applications.

Can anybody tell me what is required from the WCF setup to get it to work as the former?

Comment: kindly post your ABC config file of wcf also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I found the issue somewhere else.
I configured the client service reference to "always generate message contracts"
Unchecking this and updating the service reference solved the issue.

I found the solution here.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9655eeb-cdbb-4703-87d8-00deac340173/add-service-reference-creates-message-contracts-requestresponse-objects-with-always-generate?forum=wcf

Answer (score 0):

```
HostService client = new HostService();
```

You haven't mention what endpoint or which class object to use.Typically the servicehost class must create the object of particular end point,something like below one.

```
     using(System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost host = 
new  System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(ReceivingMethodsnamespace.ReceivingMethods )))
           {
              host.Open();
              Console.WriteLine("Host started @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
              Console.ReadLine();
           }
```

Generally the hostservice must create an object of the class which is implementing servicecontract  interface(servicename of AddressBindingContract file)

Comment: Hi Hameed, Thanks for the suggestion, the Servicehost(typeof(ReceivingMtehods) was already part of the code.